# Ruby - How to access function returned value across module

Tags: ruby, variables, scope

I am new to ruby.  I am trying to assign function returned value to global variable or constant so that I can use the value across module.

I have a Module with constants defined.  I wanted to override the constant value with the functioned returned value, so that I can use that variable across the module.  I would request you to help me in resolving this issue.

When I tried getting **NameError: undefined local variable or method `ip' for main:Object**

Thanks on advance

```
Module test

  PORT = ‘8443’
  URI=“/search/“
  $ip;

  def get_host(type, uri)  # this function is invoked by rake task  
    puts "type.. #{type}"
    hostname = get_hosttype(type)  # I wanted to assign this value to 
  end

  def get_hosttype(type)   
    ip1=“name1”
    ip2=“name2”
    if type.match(/prod/)
     host_name=ip1
    else
     host_name=ip2
    end
   ip=host_name   
  end

  URL = “https://#{ip}/#{URI}”
  puts “Final URL… #{URL}” 
end
```

Comment: I guess you are missing `$` before `ip`.

Comment: you shouldn't be using a constant if it gets redefined. You can use instance variables instead. These will be shared by the class you're including the module in. By the way the line `constant "IP"` is not valid.

Comment: @devyum - I tried using $ip as well.. but the value is not getting overrided.

Comment: @Sampath 1. its divyum :P, 2. check the answer.

Comment: @maxpleaner - my bad. removed constant "IP"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some corrections to your code along with the solution to your problem:

```
module Test # module name is constant
  PORT = '8443'
  URI  = "/search/"
  @ip  = "" # no need of ';' and keep it a instance/class variable accordingly

  def get_host(type, uri)  # this function is invoked by rake task  
    puts "type.. #{type}"
    @ip = get_hosttype(type)  # I wanted to assign this value to constant "IP"   
  end

  def get_hosttype(type)   
    ip1="name1"
    ip2="name2"
    if type.match(/prod/)
      return ip1
    else
      return ip2
    end   
  end

  def print_url
    url = "https://#{@ip}/#{URI}" # dynamic assignment of 'constant' is not allowed
    puts "Final URL… #{url}" 
  end
end

include Test
get_host("123")
print_url
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. perfect, I hope this will solve the issue.  I will try this running this and  will get back if I have any questions.

Comment: confused. After returning "ip", when I tried printing "ip" it returned nothing. But was able print "@ip" in other function/method.

Comment: @Sampath can you support your issue with an example, not sure what you are looking for?

Comment: sry if am confusing.  Let me explain with more details.  I am trying  returned IP to a global variable and use that in forming different constant URLs and call URLs in different functions.  Please refer to new block added in above code. Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: @Sampath 1. pls modify question and not add an answer for the query as it might confuse others.
2. Regarding your query: a. you can't define constants dynamically in ruby, b. you should use a method to initialize the urls you want. It's a good practice when using a module.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Test # module name is constant
 PORT = '8443'
 URI  = "/search/"
 @ip  = "" # no need of ';' and keep it a instance/class variable accordingly

def get_host(type, uri)  # this function is invoked by rake task  
  puts "type.. #{type}"
  @ip = get_hosttype(type)  # I wanted to assign this value to constant    
end

=begin
 puts @ip  #print ip to check if it is accessible outside function
 URL1 = "https://#{@ip}/#{URI}"  # use this on other function
 URL2 = "https://#{@ip}:#{PORT}/query"  #call URL2 in query function
 URL3 = "https://#{@ip}/stauts=normal"  #call URL3 in status function

def query(cookie)
  resource = RestClient::Resource.new(URL2, :verify_ssl => false)
end

def status(cookie)
  resource = RestClient::Resource.new(URL3, :verify_ssl => false)
end

=end

def get_hosttype(type)   
  ip1="name1"
  ip2="name2"
  if type.match(/prod/)
   return ip1
  else
   return ip2
  end   
 end

 def print_url
  url = "https://#{@ip}/#{URI}" # dynamic assignment of 'constant' is not allowed
 puts "Final URL… #{url}" 
  end
end

include Test
get_host("123")
print_url
```